# How in Laravel 4 to print record MySQL?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I tried to print a record in MySQL, but got an error. I have this method:

```
$aa = DB::select("select user from statystyki where id = '10'");
print $aa->user;
```

The function `mysql_fetch_array` is not working.

Answer (score 2):

`DB::select` returns an array of objects. If you `var_dump($aa)`, you can see the structure, which should look like this:

```
array(
    0 => object(stdClass)(
        'user' => 'username'
    )
)
```

You want to print the user this way:

```
$aa[0]->user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one loop. Try this way

```
$aa = DB::select("select user from statystyki where id = '10'");
foreach($aa as $user)
{
     print $user->user;
}
```